# Altering @FirestoreQuery collectionPath

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

At the moment I am using @FirestoreQuery to retrieve a project data from firebase and populate a list in SwiftUI with that data. It works all good when security rules are set to:

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{projectName=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

However, when I change security rules to:

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{projectName} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

I am getting the following error: [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at projects failed: Missing or insufficient permissions. This obviously tells me that I should change my @FirestoreQuery to listen for the documents with the following path:

`Firestore.firestore().collection("projects").whereField("owner", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")`

I am however unable to find the way to update that on the client side as @FirestoreQuery only accepts collectionPath: as a string.

My Model code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Project: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var projectName = ""
    var createdOn = Date()
    var createdBy = ""
    var projectColor = ""
    var owner = ""
    
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["projectName": projectName, "createdOn": Timestamp(date: Date()) , "createdBy": Auth.auth().currentUser?.email ?? "" , "projectColor" : projectColor, "owner": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""]
    }
}
```

Part of my View code:

```
struct MainView: View {

    @FirestoreQuery(collectionPath: "projects", predicates: [.orderBy("createdOn", true)] ) var projects: [Project]
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @EnvironmentObject var mainViewVM: MainViewModel
    
    @State private var settingsViewSheetIsPresented = false
    @State private var createProjectViewSheetIsPresented = false
    @State private var searchTerm = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            NavigationStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(projects) { project in
                        HStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color("\(project.projectColor)"))
                                .frame(width:10)
                            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                                HStack {
                                    NavigationLink {
                                        ProjectView(project: project)
                                            .environmentObject(TeamViewModel())
                                    } label: {
                                        Text(project.projectName)
                                            .font(.title2.bold())
                                            .lineLimit(1)
                                            .foregroundStyle(Color("\(project.projectColor)"))
                                    }
                                }
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Created \(project.createdOn.formatted(date:.abbreviated, time: .shortened)), by \(project.createdBy)")
                                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                                        .font(.caption2)
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                }
```

I tried to use string interps with the 'collectionPath' but it didn't work. I am very new to all of this, I am following prof. John Gallaugher's class on SwiftUI and Firebase.

UPDATE:

While I couldn't get @FQ to work as desired in my Main View, I rewrote the fetch data function with the code below. Only issue I have now is I don't have instantenous update while updating or adding documents, I had to add pull to refresh to the list.

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var projects: [Project] = []
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    init() {
        loadProjects()
    }
    func loadProjects() {
        guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else 
        { return }
        
        db.collection("projects").whereFilter(Filter.orFilter([
            Filter.whereField("owner", isEqualTo: userId),
            Filter.whereField("accessList", arrayContains: userEmail)
        ]))
            .order(by: "createdOn", descending: true)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    self.projects = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Project? in
                        try? document.data(as: Project.self)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

I call it in my Main View by on.Appear. And recall with the refreshable pull down.

It seems to work well with my updated rules:

```
    match /projects/{projectName=**} {
       allow read, update, delete: if !('owner' in resource.data) || request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
       allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.token.email_verified in resource.data.accessList || request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
       allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

Not sure if anything can be done to get instant response there?

Comment: (1) Can you point me to the course you're referring to? (2) You can use the `.where` predicate to filter for the signed in user. See the sample for an example: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/main/Example/FirestoreSample/FirestoreSample/Views/FavouriteFruitsAnimationView.swift#L50

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Peter. I couldn't get the predicates to work the way I desired - but now I've expanded my security rules too, so it felt right to just rewrite the fetch function - my Main View gets the data from there, and other nested views still use FQ Only issue is now my Main View list doesn't update instantaneously like it had with FQ. Not sure if anything can be done about that? I included new code in my OG post. The course I was following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR79dJX0UA0 - great source of knowledge, but my question was outwith the scope of the tutorial.